# Isobologram for drug combination

Tags: r

I am a newbie R user.
I am trying to write code to analysis drug synergism using isobologram according to [Tarralidar's work](http://jpet.aspetjournals.org/content/310/3/981.long#disp-formula-6)
I am not sure if I do it correctly so I tried combining a drug with its own and applied to my code.

Here is my data

```
Master.data <- rbind(data.frame(Drug = "T1", Dose = c(1,0.5,0.25,0.125), Effect = c(0.5987,0.2382,0.0602,-0.0027), DrugID = "A"),
                 data.frame(Drug = "T2", Dose = c(1,0.5,0.25,0.125), Effect = c(0.5987,0.2382,0.0602,-0.0027), DrugID = "B"),
                 data.frame(Drug = "Combo", Dose = c(2,1,0.5,0.25), Effect = c(0.7774,0.5987,0.2382,0.0602), DrugID = "Combo")
                 )
```

I use these to fit drug with drc package and plot the resulting code using ggplot2.

```
library("ggplot2")
library("drc")
#Divide data into drug group
A <- subset(Master.data, DrugID == "A")
B <- subset(Master.data, DrugID == "B")
Combo <- subset(Master.data, DrugID == "Combo")
##########################################
#Dose response curve of Drug A
A.model <- drm(Effect~Dose, data = A, fct = LL.4())
CA <- ED(A.model,50)[1,1]
q <- data.frame(Value = coef(A.model))
p1 <- data.frame(S = seq(0.05, max(Master.data$Dose), length.out = 100))
p1 <- rbind(p1,CA)
p1$v <- predict(A.model, newdata = p1)
p1$Drug <- A[1,'Drug']
#########################################
#Dose response curve of Drug B
B.model <- drm(Effect~Dose, data = B, fct = LL.4())
CB <- ED(B.model,50)[1,1]
p <- data.frame(Value = coef(B.model))
p2 <- data.frame(S = seq(0.05, max(Master.data$Dose), length.out = 100))
p2 <- rbind(p2, CB)
p2$v <- predict(B.model, newdata = p2)
p2$Drug <- B[1,'Drug']
#########################################
#Dose response curve of Combo
Combo.model <- drm(Effect~Dose, data = Combo, fct = LL.4())
ComboED50 <- ED(Combo.model,50)[1,1]
p3 <- data.frame(S = seq(0.05, max(Master.data$Dose), length.out = 100))
p3 <- rbind(p3,ComboED50)
p3$v <- predict(Combo.model, newdata = p3)
p3$Drug <- Combo[1,'Drug']
##########################################
#Plot dose response for p1,p2,p3 
p <- rbind(p1,p2,p3)
ggplot(p, aes(x = S, y = v, col = Drug)) + geom_line()+
labs(title = "Dose response curve") + xlab("Dose uM (log scale)") + ylab("Growth inhibition") +
scale_x_log10() +
ylim(min(p$v),1) +
geom_point(data = subset(Master.data,Dose != 0), aes(x = Dose, y = Effect))
##########################################
```

Which create reasonable dose-response curve.

Now I define value necessary for further calculation.

```
#######Create dose combination#########
R <- max(A$Dose)/max(B$Dose) ## Ratio of drug A and B -> R=A/B
EA <- max(A$Effect) ## Maximum effect of drug A -> EA
EB <- max(B$Effect) ## Maximum effect of drug B -> EB
CA <- ED(A.model,50)[1,1] ## Half maximum effect of drug A
CB <- ED(B.model,50)[1,1] ## Half maximum effect of drug B
```

And create table for plotting drug combination point

```
Combo.table <- data.frame(Combo$Dose)
Combo.table <- rbind(Combo.table,0)
for (i in c(1:99)) {
 Combo.table <- rbind(Combo.table,ED(Combo.model,i)[1,1])
}
Combo.table$A <- (Combo.table[,1]*R)/(R+1)
Combo.table$B <- Combo.table[,1]/(1+R)
colnames(Combo.table) <- c("Combo","A","B")
```

With this function, I create isobologram which can be applied to drug combination with a different maximum effect of each drug.

```
Iso <- function(i) {
         Isolobe <- data.frame(seq(0,ED(A.model,i)[1,1],length.out = 100))
         Isolobe <- rbind(Isolobe,CA)
         colnames(Isolobe) <- "Dose.a"
         Isolobe$Dose.b <- ED(B.model,i)[1,1]-(CB/(((EB/EA)*(1+(CA/Isolobe$Dose.a)))-1))

         ggplot(Isolobe, aes(x = Dose.a,y = Dose.b)) +
         geom_line() +
         xlab(A[1,"Drug"]) + ylab(B[1,"Drug"]) + labs(title = "Isobologram", subtitle = "Dose in uM") +
         geom_point(data = subset(Combo.table,Combo==ED(Combo.model,i)[1,1]), aes(x = A,y = B))
}
```

With all this, I executed the function.

```
Iso(50)
```

Which supposed to create Isobologram for ED50 of the combination and plot the fraction of the point of drug A,B.

The problem is from this sample, which I purposefully use the same data for drugA,B and the combo data result from one tier more of the same data. This supposed to point drug fraction on the additive line. Appearantly, it is not.

The bottomline is what did I do wrong?

Comment: In your code you have `ED(A.model,i)` but I cannot find the definition of the function `ED()`. Where this function is defined?

Comment: Function ED(drm.model, Fa) is a function come with the drc package.